# CocoaPods - pod setup Failed: /usr/bin/git checkout master

Tags: cocoapods

After I run `$sudo gem install cocoapods` and then `$pod setup`, there is an error. Please help me to fix it.

```
[!] Pod::Executable pull

Updating eaf98af..ba3c030
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

    Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/1.3.0/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK.podspec

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Aborting
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like you have an edited spec that's messing with the git repo. The easiest way to fix this would be to delete the local copy of the specs repo. From terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods; pod setup
```

EDIT:

Today (1/30/14) there was an issue with the specs repo that may make you want to fix this. Read more about it on the [CocoaPods Blog](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/)

Comment: I had to do `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos; pod setup` to get mine working again.  Perhaps they changed the folder structure since this post?

Comment: Yes we now organize that differently, edited my answer to just knock out the whole `~/.cocoapods` folder