# CocoaPods requires commit while no GIT installed

Tags: git, cocoapods

I want to install CocoaPods into my XCode project, however when I run the pod install command I get the following message:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Pod::Executable pull

Updating 094c19b..3c2b414
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

    FMDB/2.1/FMDB.podspec

    GoogleConversionTracking/1.2.0/GoogleConversionTracking.podspec

    XMPPFramework/3.6.2/XMPPFramework.podspec

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Aborting
```

The problem is that there is no GIT installed in my project folder.

```
git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Does anyone has a clue how to solve this problem? NOTE: I am not aware of changing anything in those .podspecs

Comment: possible duplicate of [CocoaPods - pod setup Failed: /usr/bin/git checkout master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825715/cocoapods-pod-setup-failed-usr-bin-git-checkout-master)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this by deleting the local copy of the CocoaPods specs repo by running `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and setting it up again with `pod setup`.

Comment: That made it work! Do you perhaps know what caused it that those 3 .podspec were seemed/were changed?