# pod install not working after updating cocoapods to 0.29

Tags: ios, git, merge, cocoapods

Here is what i did and got error. 
I wanted to use grabkit : https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit 
Before using it in my project, i updated my ruby to 2.0.0p247 and cocoapods to 0.29.
and then whenever i m going to any of my projects and try to do pod install. It gives me error saying --

"Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm '
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'"

Prior to this i was working on a repo, which i cloned, made some changes and committed.
After getting this error, i deleted that repo from my computer. and listed down all the git repos and i am 100% sure that i haven't touched any other git repo on my computer(in terms of making any changes)

Comment: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CocoaPods - pod setup Failed: /usr/bin/git checkout master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825715/cocoapods-pod-setup-failed-usr-bin-git-checkout-master)