# Cocoapod: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting

Tags: ruby, rvm, cocoapods, redditkit

It is the content of  my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'RedditKit', '~> 1.3'
```

It is placed at the root of my iOS project (i.e. not a workspace)

When I ran `pod install` I got this error message:

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] An error occurred while performing `git pull` on repo `master`.
[!] /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only

fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

I have already run `gem update --system` to update my ruby installation

More information of my `cocoapod` installation

```
$ gem which cocoapods
/Users/antkong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods.rb
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CocoaPods - pod setup Failed: /usr/bin/git checkout master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825715/cocoapods-pod-setup-failed-usr-bin-git-checkout-master)

Comment: @KeithSmiley The possible duplicate you cited is related to a totally different error message and root cause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused by a bug in libgit2. Details and solution can be found in this bug report https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2213

Comment: this worked for me, i had updated from an older version of cocoapods so i had to run $ pod repo remove master then $ pod setup.